# How to deploy SSRS reports build through Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I would be building new reports, or correcting the already built SSRS reports through report builder. Once the change is done in Development side, then how do you publish the reports on test server/UAT or on production.

What methodology is supposed to be followed?

More information: SSRS would be used of SQL Server 2008 R2 edition, Report builder version is 3.0 and database is also SQL Server 2008 R2.

Let me know if more information is required.

Please Guide Me! Thanks!!

Comment: is it need of share point for deploy of SSRS report compulsory

Answer (score 4):

With RB (and sufficient privilege), users can save reports straight to the Report Manager environment. At that point, they're deployed. But if you want to have them save those reports to a Dev/Test box, and want to push them live, there's a few options.

One easy option is to move reports into a known folder 'For Deployment'. You can then have a script which grabs the RDL for reports in here and uploads them to the proper server. You'll probably want to make sure the data sources are mapped appropriately as this method can annoyingly lose references. You can use rs.exe for your scripts, or just use the web references. PowerShell can be very useful here, as it happily talks WebService, and you can schedule PowerShell scripts using SQL Agent jobs.

Comment: thanks Rob. Any supportive links that could make things a bit more clear?

Comment: It gets discussed in this thread. I haven't read it thorough detail, but there's definitely some examples about how to use a .rss script: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/d4ba0d89-8f16-491f-8433-a375eda5627c/